# Is it okay to ask about where to find latest research publications related to computer science?

Tags: discussion

Today is my first day on this site and I want to to ask this question, but I am not sure if it's right question or ask or if it's off topic.

**Question - Is it okay to ask about where to find latest research publications related to computer science ?**

Comment: It is to broad and the obvious answer is CS journals and conference proceedings. If that does not answer your question then I would suggest explaining why you want to do so, i.e. what are you trying to do. A somewhat similar question was asked by Tim Chow awhile ago that might already answer what you want to know: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/

Comment: @Kaveh thanks for your response, actually I want to develop some product, something new to make this world a better place or at least me myself make an effort to do so. So my plan is to look at research papers and find something of my interest to start working on

Comment: I see. I think the question is too broad. There are many many computer science papers and this site is only for _theoretical_ computer science. If you are looking for a list of papers just use Google Scholar, if you are looking for _significant_ papers in computer science then there is a Wikipedia article for that. And we also have a few questions on this site about significant _theoretical_ computer science papers you can check like [this](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/what-papers-should-everyone-read).